# Network redundancy in regard to default route/gateway

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, gateway

I have two ISPs (primary is 100Mi cable on 24.x.x.x [fast but unreliable] and my backup is 1.5Mi DSL on 70.x.x.x) for redundancy and reliability.  I have dedicated Red Hat linux router firewalls connected to each service, and these are powered via UPS.  The LAN side of each firewall/router connects to a 24 port switch with the rest of the devices on my home network, including two wifi access points with the same SSID on different channels at each end of the house.

My question has two parts;

1)
How do I configure the Windows/iOS/android/linux/solaris clients to fail over to the second router if service fails on the primary (which seems to happen several times a month, almost always on a Saturday morning)?

2)
How do I signal the clients to come back to using the primary router when service is restored?

Is it possible to just list both routers when DHCP is served, and then let the client sort out what it needs?  This seems like it might work for part 1), but does nothing for part 2) unless I manually/fake fail the backup connection when the primary comes back online.

Ultimately, my goal is to maintain internet service for all my devices with no more than two minutes of outage for any service interruption, and do it without touching or reconfiguring any of the clients or routers (manually) each time it happens.

I would be happy to RTFM if only I knew the name of that manual. 
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Really this shouldn't be managed by the clients at all - they should have their gateway on the lan, and the gateway itself decides which connection to use. Is there a reason to have two separate firewalls?

Comment: Agreed.  How to automate fail-over for the clients when WAN1 the other side of the gateway on the primary router, goes away for maintenance?  The LAN 'link' to the gateway is still up, WAN1 is down.  Or perhaps the router/firewall on the primary service panics/locks/dies, the second provides redundancy.  What can I build/buy so I do not have to reset every client device for failover to service WAN2?  And back again once primary service is restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat, but `keepalived` might be an [option](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Load_Balancer_Administration/ch-keepalived-overview-VSA.html).

keepalived is a [VRRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Router_Redundancy_Protocol) implementation, which means you can define a "virtual" ip that belongs to one or the other of your routers.  Normally, you designate one as master, and one as secondary.  If the master becomes unavailable, the secondary takes ownership of the IP address.

In your scenario, this would be your clients gateway IP.  That way, they are always talking to the same IP address, and this either goes to the first or second router depending on which is master.

If the master router is down, this automatically causes the secondary to take over - the master and secondary exchange "hello" packets and as soon as the secondary no longer hears from the master, it takes over the IP.

However, you would need more to monitor the link, and let the master put itself into unavailable mode - you can do this using "track scripts".

For example, here is the config for the master:

```
vrrp_instance RouterVRRP {
  state MASTER
  interface eth0
  virtual_router_id 50
  priority 200
  advert_int 1
  virtual_ipaddress {
    10.10.10.100/32 dev eth0
  }
  track_script {
    check_google
  }
}
```

Then the track script definition:

```
vrrp_script check_google {
  script       "/scripts/pinggoogle.sh"
  interval 3   # check every 3 seconds
  fall 3       # require 3 fails for down
  rise 2       # require 2 successes back up
}
```

The script would ping google and return a 0 for all is well, and 1 for a fail.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  The virtual floating IP address was the piece I was missing to pull it all together.  I was not seeing the forest for the trees.  This is basically a poor man's cluster, and is exactly what I needed.